# Put variable name in JSON Array (fetched by an api)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am very new to Javascript but I will try to put this in convenient way. I am having this api where I am fetching the rank of a crypto (Ripple; currently ranked 7 and is subject to change overtime ), code below:

```
function myFunction() {
var url = "https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/coins/xrp-xrp";
var XRPresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var XRPjson = XRPresponse.getContentText();
var XRPdata = JSON.parse(XRPjson);
var XRPrank = XRPdata.rank;

}
```

Now this is another function for an api where I extract other infos (having 5000+ crytos listed, including ripple)

```
function myXRP() {
var url = "https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var XRP = data[7].symbol;

// Here instead of [7], I need to put the value extracted from XRPrank above so that whenever the rank is changed I get the latest value on data.[].
```

If someone could please advise.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal from your question and script. I cannot understand `Here instead of [7], I need to put the value extracted from XRPrank above so that whenever the rank is changed I get the latest value on data.[].`. Can I ask you about the result values you expect?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve. Please could you put a sample of the expected result. If you want to use the value of `myFunction()` you have to put a `return XRPrank` at the end of it. Later do something like `var XRPrank = myFunction()` inside the `myXRP()`.

Comment: In this case 7 is the current rank for Ripple coin. And and I have to pull the data for Ripple referencing from rank numbers. Since ranks are subject to change for coins. So the 1st function above was to pull the current rank for Ripple, the 2nd functions was to get other information for Ripple providing the rank value on the Array.

This got solved from though from the Answer submitted below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript there are several ways to achieve what you are looking for. The following is an adaptation of your current code with what I think are the minimal changes that you have to do, 1. use return followed by `XRPrank` 2. Call myFunction from `myXRP` and replace the data index by `XRPrank`.

```
function myFunction() {
var url = "https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/coins/xrp-xrp";
var XRPresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var XRPjson = XRPresponse.getContentText();
var XRPdata = JSON.parse(XRPjson);
var XRPrank = XRPdata.rank;

return XRPrank; // add this
 
}

function myXRP() {
var url = "https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);

var XRPrank = myFunction(); // add this

// var XRP = data[7].symbol; instead of this
var XRP = data[XRPrank].symbol; // use this

}
```

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions